# @ManyToMany java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

This is STUDENTS ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "STUDENTS")
public class Student extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(name = "student_index")
  public String index;
  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  @ManyToMany
  public List<Course> courses;
}
```

This is COURSES ENTITY

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COURSES")
public class Course extends BaseEntity {

  public String name;
  @ManyToMany
  public List<Student> students;

}
```

Which tables will be generated in DataBase?

Comment: Just a side-note: Try to never use plural wording in your relations/tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be tables
  `STUDENTS`, `COURSES`, `STUDENTS_COURSES`, `COURSES_STUDENTS`

The @ManyToMany will be confused and will create two tables `STUDENTS_COURSES`, `COURSES_STUDENTS`

To avoid such situation need to provide option `mappedBy`
ie. 
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "STUDENTS")
it will create only one table `STUDENTS_COURSES`

Comment: Thank you! I knew about mappedBy, but this was exam question, so...